# Mavensmate - Deploy only changes to static resource

Tags: static-resources, mavensmate

I am currently having trouble with deploying static resource using mavensmate. I have a static resource with a lot of images. But the only thing I'm changing is the CSS and every time I deploy the static resource, I feel like everything else is also 'redeployed' even if they are not change including the images.

Are there any other efficient way you can suggest to speed up the deployment like deploying the only change and ignore the others? I am thinking of temporarily removing the images as my last resort.

Comment: It is a static resource that is a zip? If so, you have to deploy the entire static resource every time.